# How to grab all the rows which have False in a specific column in a pandas data frame?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
    Name    Gender  Start Date  Last Login Time     Salary  Bonus%  Sr.Management    Team    
0   Douglas Male    1993-08-06  2022-07-02 12:42:00 97308   6.945   True           Marketing
1   Thomas  Male    1996-03-31  2022-07-02 06:53:00 61933   4.170   True            NaN
2   Maria   Female  1993-04-23  2022-07-02 11:17:00 130590  11.858  False           Finance
3   Jerry   Male    2005-03-04  2022-07-02 13:00:00 138705  9.340   True            Finance
4   Larry   Male    1998-01-24  2022-07-02 16:47:00 101004  1.389   True     Client Services
5   Dennis  Male    1987-04-18  2022-07-02 01:35:00 115163  10.125  False            Legal
6   Ruby    Female  1987-08-17  2022-07-02 16:20:00 65476   10.012  True             Product
```

I'm actually trying to grab all the rows which are having False in `Sr.Management` column and I'm unable to do that. However, I'm able to grab all the rows which are having True in the same column by running `df[df["Senior Management"]]`.

Please help me in getting False values :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
df[~df['Sr.Management']]

     Name  Gender  Start_Date  ...  Bonus% Sr.Management     Team
2   Maria  Female  1993-04-23  ...  11.858         False  Finance
5  Dennis    Male  1987-04-18  ...  10.125         False    Legal
```